# Placing text above div

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

Here's my issue. What I'm trying to do is create a page where the DIV with the ID as Q1 only gets filled in if that page deserves an advertisement, and I'll use PHP code along with data from MySQL to determine that. Let's say for the time being that the page I'm working on deserves an ad.

The code I provided allows me to load an adsense ad inside the div after the page has been completely loaded.

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
Content....
Content....
Content....
<div id="Q1"></div>
Content....
Content....
Content....
<div id="HAB">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var google_ad_client="ca-pub-xxxxxx";
    var google_ad_slot="yyyyy";
    var google_ad_width=320;
    var google_ad_height=50;
    var data_page_url="http://example.com"; 
  </script>
  <script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('Q1').appendChild(document.getElementById('HAB'));
  var a=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
  if(a){a.title="Advertisement";} 
</script></body></html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#Q1{display:block;width:320px;height:50px}
#Q1{margin:20px 0}@media screen and (min-width: 348px){#Q1{float:left;margin:12px}}
```

Now the problem is adding a label. Let's call it "Advertisement". The only way the label must appear is if the actual advertisement is loaded. This means that I cannot just change `<div id="Q1"></div>` to `Advertisement<br><div id="Q1"></div>` or the word `Advertisement` appears regardless of whether the ad loads or not.

I even tried adding the word `Advertisement` within `<div id="HAB">` and enclosing the ad code inside another div within that, and I still have no success. Instead of the advertisement fitting in the box, it shifts downward by the number of pixels in height the word `Advertisement` needs.

Overall, what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the actual advertisement along with the word `advertisement` on top of it to show in a borderless box with margins, but both items can only appear if the page deserves an advertisement. If the page does not deserve one, then no advertisement will show and the word `advertisement` will not show.

Also, I need a solution compatible with Internet Explorer 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: what language are you using for sever side?

Comment: PHP. also, if the page results in an error, then I want no ad to show. But I need the solution in html/javascript/css format

Comment: I understand but if you are using data from database , then you have to use  php also. Also, I am not sure what you are looking for?

Comment: I want it where (assuming the page deserves an ad) the advertisement is directly under text and then both appear inside the div with id Q1 after the page loads without the ad falling out of the box.

Comment: Maybe I am oversimplifying it but I believe it is just a matter of using if else either in php or javascript depending on how you are loading your data from database. Can you fiddle it (what you want it to look like)?

Comment: nevermind. I think I figured it out. I had to put the word in its own HTML element right before DIV with the ID "HAB" and then I used appendchild twice. now I gotta test my theory on all browsers